# How to pass multiple parameters to middleware with OR condition in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to set permission to access an action to two different user roles Admin, Normal_User as shown below.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role_check:Normal_User','role_check:Admin']], function() {
        Route::get('/user/{user_id}', array('uses' => 'UserController@showUserDashboard', 'as' => 'showUserDashboard'));
    });
```

This route can be accessed by either Admin or Normal_user. But in this middleware configuration, user is required to be both Admin and Normal_User. How can I add OR condition in middleware parameter passing? Or is there any other method to give permission?

The following is my middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
    {
        if ($role != Auth::user()->user_role->role ) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            }
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Can anyone please reply?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To add multiple parameters, you need to seperate them with a comma:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role_check:Normal_User,Admin']], function() {
        Route::get('/user/{user_id}', array('uses' => 'UserController@showUserDashboard', 'as' => 'showUserDashboard'));
    });
```

Then you have access them to in your middleware like so:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role1, $role2) {..}
```

The logic from there is up to you to implement, there is no automatic way to say "OR".

Answer (score 27):

You can use the 3 dot (...) syntax in PHP 5.6+

***Your middleware's handle function***

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
{
    foreach($roles as $role){
        if ($request->user()->hasRole($role)){
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
    abort(404);
}
```

Comment: It's called "splat operator"

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 16):

Instead of adding multiple arguments to your handle method and having to update it every time you add a new role to your application, you can make it dynamic.

**Middleware**

```
 /**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param $request
 * @param Closure $next
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

    $roles = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2); // [default, admin, manager]

    foreach ($roles as $role) {

        try {

            Role::whereName($role)->firstOrFail(); // make sure we got a "real" role

            if (Auth::user()->hasRole($role)) {
                return $next($request);
            }

        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $exception) {

            dd('Could not find role ' . $role);

        }
    }

    Flash::warning('Access Denied', 'You are not authorized to view that content.'); // custom flash class

    return redirect('/');
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role_check:default,admin,manager']], function() {
    Route::get('/user/{user_id}', array('uses' => 'UserController@showUserDashboard', 'as' => 'showUserDashboard'));
});
```

This will check if the authenticated user has at least one of the roles provided and if so, passes the request to the next middleware stack. Of course the `hasRole()` method and the roles themselves will need to be implemented by you.

Comment: Nice. It's surprising that the Laravel docs don't cover the case whereby you want an unknown number of parameters to be passed to the middleware.

Answer (score 3):

This super easy dynamic implementation might come handy for someone, in your middlewear file checkRole.php:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ... $roles)
{
    $found = false;
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if (session('type') == $role) {
            $found = true; break;
        }
    }

    if (!$found) {
        return back()->with('error','Access denied!');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

and call the middlewear from web.php with as much parameter you need to pass:

```
Route::get('/approve',  'aController@approve')  ->middleware('roles:admin');
Route::get('/dashboard','bController@dashboard')->middleware('roles:admin,user');
```

also don't forget to modify the middlewear key name in your Kernel.php:

```
'roles' => \App\Http\Middleware\checkRole::class,
```

Answer (score 2):

```
            //please take note there must be space between ... $roles

        //on your route make sure there is no space in between the roles 
        'checkRole:staff,admin'

        public function handle($request, Closure $next, ... $roles)
        {
        foreach($roles as $role){
        if ($request->user()->hasRole($role)){
        return $next($request);
        }
        }
        abort(404);
        }

        you can try this out also 


        Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:webdev|admin'], function () {
        });
        public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)

        {
        $roles = collect(explode('|',$role));
        if (! $request->user()->hasRole($roles)) {
        abort(404, 'No Way');
        }
        return $next($request);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the middleware class

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Middleware;

 use Closure;
 use function abort;
 use function array_flip;
 use function array_key_exists;
 use function array_slice;
 use function func_get_args;

 class MustBeOFUserType
 {
     /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
     public function handle($request, Closure $next)
     {
        $roles = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);  // ['admin', 'author']

        //flip $roles to get ['admin' => 0, 'author' => 1];
        if (!auth()->guest() && array_key_exists(auth()->user()->role->name, array_flip($roles))) {

          return $next($request);
        }
        abort(423, 'Sorry you are not authrized !');

     }
   }
```

in the web.php OR route file

```
Route::get('/usertype', function() {

   return response(['Accessed'], 200);
})->middleware([
    'App\Http\Middleware\MustBeOFUserType:admin,author'
]);
```

**Remember space on** ':admin,author' like ':admin, author' will result into errors

For sanity check and if your a TDD person like I am  use this to test the middleware

```
<?php

 namespace Tests\Feature;

 use App\User;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
 use Tests\TestCase;
 use function factory;

 class MustBeOFUserTypeTest extends TestCase
 {
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test * */
    public function it_accepts_the_admin()
    {
       $this->signIn(factory(User::class)->states('administrator')->create());

       $this->get('/usertype')->assertStatus(200);
     }

     /** @test * */
     public function it_rejects_normal_users()
     {
       $this->signIn();

       $this->get('/usertype')->assertStatus(423);
      }

      /** @test **/
      public function it_accepts_authors()
      {

        $this->signIn(factory(User::class)->states('author')->create());

        $this->get('/usertype')->assertStatus(200);
       }

       public function signIn($user = null)
       {

            $u = $user ?: factory('App\User')->states('normal')->create();

             $this->be($u);

             return $this;
            }
       }
```