# How to use 'OR' middleware for route laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've two types for user and I've created multiple middlewares.

Some routes need to allow for both type of user.

I've trying following code:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Common', 'middleware' => ['Auth1', 'Auth2']], function() {
    Route::get('viewdetail', array('as' => 'viewdetail', 'uses' => 'DashboardController@viewdetail'));
});
```

But its not working :(

Comment: Most suitable for authorization (gates and policies) than middlewares

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Middleware is supposed to either return a response or pass the request down the pipeline. Middlewares are independent of each other and shouldn't be aware of other middlewares run.

You'll need to implement a separate middleware that allows 2 roles or single middleware that takes allowed roles as parameters.

**Option 1**: just create a middleware is a combined version of Auth1 and Auth2 that checks for 2 user types. This is the simplest option, although not really flexible.

**Option 2**: since **version 5.1** middlewares can take parameters - see more details here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware#middleware-parameters. You could implement a single middleware that would take list of user roles to check against and just define the allowed roles in your routes file. The following code should do the trick:

```
// define allowed roles in your routes.php
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Common', 'middleware' => 'checkUserRoles:role1,role2', function() {
  //routes that should be allowed for users with role1 OR role2 go here
}); 

// PHP < 5.6
// create a parametrized middleware that takes allowed roles as parameters
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

  // will contain ['role1', 'role2']
  $allowedRoles = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);

  // do whatever role check logic you need
}

// PHP >= 5.6
// create a parametrized middleware that takes allowed roles as parameters
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles) {

  // $roles will contain ['role1', 'role2']

  // do whatever role check logic you need
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This example 
[How to pass multiple parameters to middleware with OR condition in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712282/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-middleware-with-or-condition-in-laravel-5-2)

Instead of adding multiple arguments to your handle method and having to update it every time you add a new role to your application, you can make it dynamic.

**Middleware**

```
 /**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param $request
 * @param Closure $next
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

    $roles = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2); // [default, admin, manager]

    foreach ($roles as $role) {

        try {

            Role::whereName($role)->firstOrFail(); // make sure we got a "real" role

            if (Auth::user()->hasRole($role)) {
                return $next($request);
            }

        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $exception) {

            dd('Could not find role ' . $role);

        }
    }

    Flash::warning('Access Denied', 'You are not authorized to view that content.'); // custom flash class

    return redirect('/');
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role_check:default,admin,manager']], function() {
    Route::get('/user/{user_id}', array('uses' => 'UserController@showUserDashboard', 'as' => 'showUserDashboard'));
});
```

This will check if the authenticated user has at least one of the roles provided and if so, passes the request to the next middleware stack. Of course the `hasRole()` method and the roles themselves will need to be implemented by you.

**You can use php 5.6**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
{
    foreach ($roles as $role) {

        try {
            if ($request->user()->can($role)) {
              return $next($request);
        }

        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $exception) {
          abort(403);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:manager,admin'], function () {}
```

In middleware named 'role' you can destruct arguments into array

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
{
    $userRole = $request->user()->role;

    if (! $userRole || ! in_array($userRole->name, $roles)) {
        abort(403);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply You can use like this syntax that means if has one of them

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:first|second|third|....']], function () {});
```