# Laravel Passport - Allow either auth:api OR client_creds in route group

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-middleware

I would like a group of routes to be accessible with either the standard `auth:api` middleware, or via the `CheckClientCredentials` middleware.

I can't see how this would be possible as there is no ability to set middleware as only requiring one of the listed middleware.

Is there a Passport middleware which allows any type of API authentication that I don't know about?

Or is there a clean way of creating a custom middleware which tests for either of the middleware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took Joshuas advice about the [similar answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344836/how-to-use-or-middleware-for-route-laravel-5/39346307#39346307) and created a new middleware encompassing the two auth middleware.

Working Middleware class for anyone else hitting this issue below. This will try the Auth guard middleware first and if this fails to authenticate the request it will then try to authenticate using the Client Credentials Passport middleware.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as AuthGuardMiddleware;
use Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials as ClientCredMiddleware;


class AuthenticateWithApiOrClientCreds
{

    /**
    * Authenticate a request with either Authenticate OR CheckClientCredentials Middleware
    *
    * @param $request
    * @param Closure $next
    * @param  mixed  ...$scopes
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
    */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$scopes)
    {
        $auth_guard_middleware  = app()->make(AuthGuardMiddleware::class);

        try {
            $response = $auth_guard_middleware->handle($request, $next, 'api');

        } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
            $client_cred_middleware = app()->make(ClientCredMiddleware::class);
            $response = $client_cred_middleware->handle($request, $next, ...$scopes);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn't provide the *OR* middleware. Although there are several workarounds like it was previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39346307/9918309).

If you are looking for the way to change the `api.php` default middleware (default to `auth:api`), you can see it in directory: `app\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php` with function name: `mapApiRoutes()`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up storing all the routes that need authentication in a separate route file called `api-authenticated.php`. In RouteServiceProvider.php I'm applying the `web` and `api` middleware groups for those routes conditionally based on the presence of the Authorization header. When the Authorization header is set, you know the user is an API client.

In `Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```php
/**
 * Define the "api" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes are typically stateless.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api')
        ->middleware('api')
        ->namespace($this->apiNamespace)
        ->name('api.')
        ->group(__DIR__ . '/../../routes/api.php');
}

/**
 * Define the authenticated "api" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes are typically stateless, but are also used in
 * a stateful context as the first-party uses cookies for
 * authenticaton
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function mapAuthenticatedApiRoutes()
{
    $stateless = request()->hasHeader('Authorization');

    Route::prefix('api')
        ->middleware($stateless ? ['api', 'auth:api'] : ['web', 'auth'])
        ->namespace($this->apiNamespace)
        ->name('api.')
        ->group(__DIR__  . '/../../routes/api-authenticated.php');
}
```