# Laravel - How to OR among middlewares for a route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, laravel-middleware

There is a table `users` in my website and a user is allowed to update a user if it is admin or it is his/her account. I can put this rule inside a middleware and impose it on the route but I want to create separate middlewares and `OR` among them. Can I do that?

The following code

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin','Owner']],
    function () {
        Route::resource('roles', 'RoleController');
        Route::resource('locations', 'LocationController');
        Route::resource('recipients', 'RecipientController');
        Route::resource('classifications', 'ClassificationController');
    });
```

has `AND` behavior. I think it is possible to do this using some `if ... else ...` statement inside the `web.php` or the `UserController` but I need to know if there is any other way out.

Thanks in advance

---

### update

Here is Owner middleware

```
class OwnerMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $id)
    {
        if(Auth::guest())
            return abort(403, 'Access Denied');
        if(Auth::user()->id != $id)
            return abort(403, 'Access Denied');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then I pass the `$id` parameter to it.

Comment: Can we see your Owner middleware code?

Comment: Hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344836/how-to-use-or-middleware-for-route-laravel-5

Comment: @aceraven777 I update the code

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't an "OR" for middleware. It either acts or passes. You have to expand the current middleware to check ownership or permission to edit.

However, I'd recommend using a policy with middleware to resolve this:
See: https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#via-middleware