# Auth or auth-api middleware in api routes in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

For apis auth I am currently using:

```
Route::group([
  'middleware' => 'auth:api'
], function() {
    Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
});
```

If I want to use same for session based logins do I need to create same routes in web.php file or can I set up middleware in AuthController constructor with something like this or this?

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39346307/10230696) 'auth:api' means auth is checking for api so do I need to pass anything there to check for sessions like 'auth:api,web' or what?

Answer (score 0):

Create same routes in web.php just ommit the middleware, as web middleware is applied automatically. Same goes for api.php, auth:api is default middleware there.