# How to add 'OR' condition to call middleware on Laravel Routes?

Tags: laravel, routes

I want to add 'OR' condition with middleware on laravel routes for Role and Permission. Can anyone please help me here. Below is the code which I am trying currently through some internet research but it is not working.

```
Route::get('get-all-users', 'API\Admin\AdminController@get_all_users')->middleware(['role:admin' OR 'permission:view.all.users']);
```

Comment: Remove the `OR` add a `,`. Technically you would need both.

Comment: Actually, I have not attached all permission to admin, and permission can be created dynamically. So, If a new user attached with selected permission or 'Admin' should access this API. I don't need both, either role admin or user to have permission.

Comment: What package are you using for these roles and permissions.

Comment: are you creating role based access controll ?? Btw for you question here may be the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344836/how-to-use-or-middleware-for-route-laravel-5

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Not really, as per your answer, I have to attach all permissions to admin as well so that I have to check for permission only not for roles. But I don't want it, I want either user has role or permission.

Comment: @RamanJoshi But how come a user has a permission without a role?

Comment: @vivek_23 User is having a role but the role is generating dynamically by admin itself with predefined permissions. So I cannot check only roles in routes as well. So for the dynamic roles, I have to check permissions.

Comment: Also, as per package **ultraware/roles** we can attach only permission to user without roles.

Comment: @RamanJoshi _So for the dynamic roles, I have to check permissions - exactly. Hence I mentioned to just check if role has that permission. According to the package you mentioned, you can check for permission https://github.com/ultraware/roles#checking-for-permissions

Comment: Hence the only solution left is that I have to create a new middleware in which I have to check whether the user has role **Admin** or has permission **view.all.users** then authorize him. And this solution is already known to me.

Comment: @RamanJoshi I haven't gone through the whole package but I am sure you can fetch the role from the user(getting user using Auth::user() I guess) and from that you can check if the role has the permission. If you have directly attached permission to the user, then you would need both middlewares. When you do `return $next($request)` , you may have to pass something in `$request`, so the other middleware knows the request has already passed the first check.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario,  you will need to change the DB structure a bit. Tables would look like:

- Actions
- Roles
- Role_action_mapping => This will have foreign keys of both the above tables as a many to many relationship.

Now, every action should have a role assigned to it. So, the permission `view.all.users` will have an entry in the table with `admin`(or any desired role) assigned to it by it's side in `Role_action_mapping`.

So all you will have to do is have a single middleware say `permission:view.all.users` on the route and just check if the current `role` of the user has an entry with `view.all.users` in the `Role_action_mapping` table.