# Multiple middleware not working on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I have a route resource group that can only be accessible by one of 2 middleware rules. I have registered them both and they both work independently if I test them both out alone, but when I have them together they don't work

I have tried running them both as either an "or" statement (which means the middleware works as intended) but this means that anyone not logged in can also access the routes for some reason. If I use a comma to separate the middleware, it's blocked for everyone. I know both middleware works ok as they do work if I try them independently. I am using the below code

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['IsAdmin' or 'IsPatreon']], function(){
Route::resource('patreon', 'patreonGalleryController', ['names'=>[

  'index'=>'patreonGallery.index',
  'create'=>'patreonGallery.create',
  'store'=>'patreonGallery.store',
  'edit'=>'patreonGallery.edit',
  'show'=>'patreonGallery.show',
  'destroy'=>'patreonGallery.destroy',
  ]]);
});
```

How can I set it so that only either admin or patreon uses can see the paths?

Comment: You can't apply middleware with an OR conditional. If you say both the user has to pass both to get routed. Here's a way to use either/or middleware (but it's from 2016). https://stackoverflow.com/a/38712654/3585500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two middlewares are working separately.
IsAdmin is checking that user is admin
IsPatreon is checking that user is patreon...

You cannot merge these 2 middlewares by `OR` Operator

Probably you need to create new middelware, something like 
`IsAdminOrPatreon` and do you checks inside of that middleware and assing that middleware to your Group..

Or you can try with middleware parameters, for example

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['checkRoles:admin,patreon']], function(){
  Route::resource('patreon', 'patreonGalleryController', ['names'=>[

    'index'=>'patreonGallery.index',
    'create'=>'patreonGallery.create',
    'store'=>'patreonGallery.store',
    'edit'=>'patreonGallery.edit',
    'show'=>'patreonGallery.show',
    'destroy'=>'patreonGallery.destroy',
  ]]);
});
```

And in you `checkRoles` middleware get the `admin` and `patreaon` roles like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

    // will contain ['role1', 'role2']
    $allowedRoles = array_slice(func_get_args(), 2);

    // here you can loop and check your roles
}
```

Note! If you pass `'checkRoles:admin,patreon'` you will get

```
array(admin,patreon)
```

If you pass `'checkRoles:admin'` you will get

```
array(admin)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't use `or` condition inside middleware array. middleware array always return `and` condition. you can specify the user role inside your middleware.

- [gist sample role middleware](https://gist.github.com/amochohan/8cb599ee5dc0af5f4246#file-checkrole-php)
- https://gist.github.com/ivanhoe011/931417be3e36b3f06e994bfe5cd004f9

Answer (score -1):

You do something like this in your controller.

```
  public function __construct()
{
    return ($this->middleware('IsAdmin')) || $this->middleware('IsPatreon');
}
```

Each route on this controller will be authenticated by any one of middleware.

Comment: I just tested, this doesn't work it only validates one user guard.