# Laravel - Middleware custom typed Request parameter

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-8, type-hinting

I want to use `VacancyListRequest` to pass through middleware parameters and use its rules to validate them before controller action. I know that middleware acts Pipeline pattern, but does anybody know how to use any custom type except default `\Illuminate\Http\Request`?

**Middleware**

```
public function handle(VacancyListRequest $request, Closure $next)
{
    $request = $this->analizeQuery($request);
    $request = $this->formatValues($request);
    $request = $this->prepareParams($request);

    return $next($request);
}
```

**Controller**

```
 public function index(VacancyListRequest $request, bool $asQuery = false)
```

**Error**

> App\Http\Middleware\Vacancy\BeforeVacancyIndexRequestMiddleware::handle():
> Argument #1 ($request) must be of type
> App\Http\Requests\Vacancy\VacancyListRequest, Illuminate\Http\Request
> given,

Comment: What is the reason for type casting `handle(VacancyListRequest $request, Closure $next)` ?  You were expecting that every request will be type of `VacancyListRequest`.

Comment: [This answer will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712282/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-middleware-with-or-condition-in-laravel-5-2)

Comment: @InsaneSkull I want to make middleware to specfic type of request and perform some actions before it's using in controller (like some analize stuff and query building which depends on data of request) and then USE RULES of this specific type on this request (cause dont want to move validation and auth logic from ther). More of that - i want to pass some vars from middleware to controller in this type of request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because you are passing the `$request` as argument of the handle method of you middleware which is typed as `VacancyListRequest` instead of being of type `Illuminate\Http\Request`.

You should change the middleware to be like this

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Closure;
 
class VacancyListRequest
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request = $this->analizeQuery($request);
        $request = $this->formatValues($request);
        $request = $this->prepareParams($request);


        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

But in your controller It should be like this

```
// At the top of you controller file you add this 
use App\Http\Requests\Vacancy\VacancyListRequest;


// And define the controller method like this 
public function index(VacancyListRequest $request, bool $asQuery = false)
```

> It's a must for the first parameter of the `handle` method to be of type `\Illuminate\Http\Request` like it defined in the docs [# Defining Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#defining-middleware)

Comment: I don't understand the question - I WANT to use CUSTOM type of request in the middleware and the question was about how to work around using only Request default type