# Passing options to middleware in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, middleware

I have the following in my controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('contactpermissionschecker', array(
      'requiredAccess' => array(
         'canEdit' => 1,
         'canDelete' => 1,
      )
    ));
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to access "canEdit" and "canDelete" in the middleware here:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    print_r($request->requiredAccess);
}
```

Above I'm just trying to print it out from the request, but that doesn't work. I also tried:

```
$this->options
```

But also, not there. Any ideas how to get these variables in middleware?

Comment: This may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38712282/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-middleware-with-or-condition-in-laravel-5-2

Answer (score 0):

try adding requiredAccess to handle method args.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $requiredAccess)
{
   print_r($requiredAccess);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i have gone through document and other articles, and noted down that laravel middleware do not support `multidimentional` and `associative` array.
If you would like to pass parameter as array then you have to use `|` deliminator.

```html
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('contactpermissionschecker:canEdit|canAccess');
}
```

```html
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $requiredAccess)
{
   $requestData = explode("|", $requiredAccess);
   foreach ($requestData as $key => $value) {
      dd($value);
   }
}
```